# Cell Fracture Addon Generating pieces that go beyond the original mesh

Tags: modeling, geometry, cell-fracture

Whenever I use a mesh that's more complex than the cube, (even the monkey), I often end up with results like this:

Original mesh for fracturing:
[image: Original mesh with particles for fracturing:]

Cell Fracture settings:

[image: Cell Fracture settings:]

Results with weird extra geometry:
[image: Results with weird extra geometry:]

Same thing in a different angle:

[image: Same thing different angle:]

Working on Blender 3.0.0 on Windows 10. Any help you guys could give would be amazing. If there's any more information I need to provide, please just let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gues this happens because of Non Manifold geometry. Cell Fracture is a **boolean based addon**. So to make it work properly you need to close all the gaps in Suzanne.
To search and fix the problem follow next steps:

1. Select the mesh and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter the Edit Mode
2. Press <kbd>LMB</kbd> anywhere in viewport to reset selection
3. Make sure that you are in Vertex or Edge Selection Mode
4. In Viewport Header go to *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold* to inspect the model and find the gaps
5. Press <kbd>Z</kbd> *> Wireframe* to switch to Wireframe Shading. Now you can see the gaps clearly. These gaps mean that Suzanne **consists of three Non Manifold objects** the head and two eyes. And the result whitch we'll get after Cell Fracture(a lot of boolean operations) most likely will be poor. If you take a look at your screenshots - all problems are located at those gaps place
6. Hover the mouse cursor over the eyes one at a time and press <kbd>L</kbd> to use Select Linked
7. Press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces* to delete selected eyes
8. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select edge loops around the gaps and press <kbd>F</kbd> to Fill them
9. Repeat the Cell Fracture operation and enjoy the result

[image]

Of course you can work on geometry more properly to get nicer eyes fo the monkey)